# Testing i18next locales in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, internationalization, i18next

I have a function that returns locale as follows:

**getVal.ts**

```
import i18next from 'i18next';

export const getVal = (val) => {
return i18next.t('value', { val })
}
```

and a test

**getVal.spec.ts**

```
describe('get value', () => {
it("return the value expected", () => {
expect(getVal()).toBe('two')
})})
```

this however returns an `undefined` error and I am not sure how to go about it. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `val` variable you've used on `getVal` is not defined, so it's probably the one resulting in your `undefined` error. Try adding the type as below:

```
import i18next from 'i18next';

export const getVal = (val:any) => {
return i18next.t('value', { val })
}
```

I picked type `any` because I haven't looked into i18next as much so I don't know what type the function returns. I also tried type `number` and the tests still passed so I'm not sure what type the `i18next.t`  function returns. Also it may be because I tried this on Angular.
You can look into https://react.i18next.com/latest/typescript to make the function fully-typed. It seems completely different on React. Lemme know how it goes!

Comment: sorry just edited that to make it exist but the value is still undefined on the test